# Create a static initializer for UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create an extension to UIView with a static initializer (for example like `new`). In my old Objective-C projects I would create a Category with the following implementation:

```
+ (instancetype)autoLayout {
    UIView *view = [self new];
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    return view;
}
```

But I can't find a way to do this in swift. I thought about creating a normal class function:

```
class func autolayout() {
    let view = self.init()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

}
```

.. but what should be the return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using extensions on class functions you should use `Self` as this implies it is the object is type of self.

`Self` can be used on class functions and in protocols.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

extension UIView {

  class func autoLayout() -> Self {
    let view = self.init()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
  }

}

let view = UIView.autoLayout()
```